# Define a property using methods from the parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I have a class which defines a couple of `set` and `get` methods:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
```

I want this class to use properties, but I don't want to alter it's code (or add anything). So I tried inheriting like so:

```
class Child(MyClass):

    name = property(get_name, set_name)
```

When I try and import `Child`, I get a NameError: 'get_name' is not defined.

I presume this is because the property declaration has to go **after** tbe `get` and `set` methods?

Is there anyway to do this in `Child` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the methods on the parent class:

```
class Child(MyClass):
    name = property(MyClass.get_name, MyClass.set_name)
```

Within a class definition 'body', the getter and setter functions are still local names and you can thus address them as such. But in the subclass they are no longer local, so you need to retrieve them from the class.